# Is there a way to traverse shared_ or any "smart" ptr over an array?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

From what I know smart pointer should be equilvalent to "raw" pointer with the difference that it is safe. Ok, but if I have regular pointer:

```
int* p = new int[10];
fill(p, p + 10, 0);//this will work for regular pointer but not for smart one.
```

Same with hand written loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
*p[i] = 0;
}
```

This is not possible (I think) for smart poiner. So the question is, how can I initialized array to which pointer I have stored in one of smart pointers (let's assume shared_ptr)?

Comment: You don't have an array of pointers there, but a pointer to an array of integers. Is this really what you mean?

Comment: @BjörnPollex I no where mentioned that I have an array of pointers.

Comment: You are right, I misread your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it might be easier just to use `std::vector<int>`. If your array has an unchanging size, though, then perhaps `std::vector<int>` is indeed better replaced with a smart pointer.

With that out of the way, your first choice should be a `std::unique_ptr`, specifically the array specialization: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. (If you don't, the smart pointer will use `delete` instead of `delete[]` on your pointer, leading to undefined behavior.) Your code would become:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);
std::fill(p.get(), p.get() + 10, 0);
```

As you can see, smart pointers have a `get()` method that returns the underlying pointer.

From here, if you need to use a `std::shared_ptr`, things become a big dangerous (do to unfortunate oversight, as far as I know). That oversight is that `std::shared_ptr` has no array specialization:

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int[10]);
} // oops! calls delete x.get(); instead of delete [] x.get(); ... UB!
```

However, `std::shared_ptr` can easily correct this like so:

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>());
} // correctly uses delete [] x.get()
```

From this point, the code is the same:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>());
std::fill(p.get(), p.get() + 10, 0);
```

---

Note that `std::shared_ptr` provides a constructor to construct from a `std::unique_ptr`, which properly uses the deleter. So this is safe:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);
std::shared_ptr<int> p2(std::move(p)); // okay, uses std::default_delete<int[]>()
```

Comment: If it has an unchanging size, wouldn't `std::array<int, N>` be a better choice?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Then `N` would have to be known at compile-time. I mean unknown until run-time, but unchanging once known.

Comment: I've also (recently) seen it suggested that one "should" in any case use a `shared_ptr<vector<int>>` or `shared_ptr<array<int,10>>`in preference to a shared ptr to a C-style array even with the right deleter. And likewise for `unique_ptr`, don't use the array specialization. I'm not sure whether I agree or not, but avoiding `new[]` certainly means you don't have to worry about `delete[]`.

Comment: As an alternative though, `template <typename T> unique_ptr<T[]> new_array(size_t n) { return new T[n]; }` followed by `shared_ptr<int> p = new_array<int>(10);` looks pretty reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you declare your array using a smart-pointer like this:

```
boost::shared_array<int> p = new int[10];
```

The call to your `fill`-function would the look like this:

```
fill(p.get(), p.get() + 10, 0);
```

`p.get()` returns the raw pointer that is managed by the smart-pointer. Your loop would require no adjustment, but it was wrong in the first place:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    p[i] = 0; // no dereferencing required here
}
```

Comment: I am not sure myself, so I changed it to `boost::shared_array`.

Comment: I looked in my copy of the standard, and could only find `shared_ptr` so I think its only in boost.